# Can't figure out what's wrong in the rpm file

Tags: rpm

The attached rpm file(https://github.com/sparkleholic/helpme/blob/master/wowtest.rpm) what I made is not installed properly.
But I couldn't figure out the problem in.

It'll be helpful,  any comment, any exam about this.. Plz.

Comment: Provide the source. No one will touch the resulting binary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out this though debugging rpm v5.
There're two file list in rpm, one is in the rpm header and other is in cpio elements.
During installing rpm via rpm5, it pops an element from cpio and search it from file list in rpm header via bsearch function.
That's why the attached file failed during installation.
file list should be sorted in order to be used by bsearch().

With sorted file list info in rpm header, installation is working fine.

Comment: Yes, files in a *.rpm (and in the cpio ball de facto) are expected to be sorted so that bsearch(3) can be use for performance. How was the *.rpm file generated without being sorted (which is a bug in some version of rpmbuild or clone)?

Comment: I wrote a small source code to make rpm when I posted this question. It didn't use the rpmbuild command.

Comment: So sort the files before generating the header and payload.